# Erro de syntax em script variação de produtos jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tenho um script em jQuery, que basicamente filtra as variações de produtos do Woocomerce Wordpress e seleciona a opção desejada adicionando o atributo "selected", o grande problema é que, eu tenho um botão para selecionar a variação, como podem ver na imagem abaixo, só que independente do lugar onde eu clique na variação, ela é selecionada, já testei diversas formas, mas estão surgindo alguns bugs, o que eu precisava é que, somente ao clicar no "SELECIONAR" o item fosse selecionado, aqui está o link caso queiram dar uma olhada em funcionamento:

https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/produto/caixas-de-tomadas/mobiliario/spe-2702/

agradeço desde já a ajuda!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
;(function ( $ ) {
'use strict';

/**
 * @TODO Code a function the calculate available combination instead of use WC hooks
 */
$.fn.tawcvs_variation_swatches_form = function () {
 return this.each( function() {
  var $form = $( this ),
   $vselect = $('.variation-select'),
   clicked = null,
   selected = [];

  $form.addClass( 'swatches-support' )
  $vselect.on( 'click', '.selecionar, .selecionado', function ( e ) {
   e.preventDefault();
   e.stopPropagation(); // para nao haver bubbling do evento para os pais
   var $el = $( this ).parents( '.swatch' ),
     $select = $el.closest( '.value' ).find( 'select' ),
     attribute_name = $select.data( 'attribute_name' ) || $select.attr( 'name' ),
     value = $el.data( 'value' );

    $select.trigger( 'focusin' );

    // Check if this combination is available
    if ( ! $select.find( 'option[value="' + value + '"]' ).length ) {
     $el.siblings( '.swatch' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
     $select.val( '' ).change();
     $form.trigger( 'tawcvs_no_matching_variations', [$el] );
     return;
    }

    clicked = attribute_name;

    if ( selected.indexOf( attribute_name ) === -1 ) {
     selected.push(attribute_name);
    }

    if ( $el.hasClass( 'selected' ) && e.currentTarget.className == "selecionado" ) {
     $select.val( '' );
     $el.removeClass( 'selected' );

     delete selected[selected.indexOf(attribute_name)];
    } else {
     $el.addClass( 'selected' ).siblings( '.selected' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
     $select.val( value );
    }

    $select.change();
   } )
   .on( 'click', '.reset_variations', function () {
    $( this ).closest( '.variations_form' ).find( '.swatch.selected' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
    selected = [];
   } )
   .on( 'tawcvs_no_matching_variations', function() {
    window.alert( wc_add_to_cart_variation_params.i18n_no_matching_variations_text );
   } );
 } );
};

$( function () {
 $( '.variations_form' ).tawcvs_variation_swatches_form();
 $( document.body ).trigger( 'tawcvs_initialized' );
} );

})( jQuery );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<td class="value">
<div class="variation-selector variation-select-image hidden">
<select id="pa_opcoes-de-acabamento" class="" name="attribute_pa_opcoes-de-acabamento" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_opcoes-de-acabamento" data-show_option_none="yes">
        <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
        <option value="spe-2702-tba-pi" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702-TBA-PI</option>
        <option value="spe-2702-tba-po" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702-TBA-PO</option>
        <option value="spe-2702-tbi" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702-TBI</option>
        <option value="spe-2702-tbm" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702-TBM</option>
        <option value="spe-2702q-cz" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702Q-CZ</option>
        <option value="spe-2702q-pr" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702Q-PR</option>
        <option value="spe-2702r-cz" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702R-CZ</option>
        <option value="spe-2702r-pr" class="attached enabled">SPE-2702R-PR</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="tawcvs-swatches" data-attribute_name="attribute_pa_opcoes-de-acabamento">
<span class="swatch swatch-image swatch-spe-2702-tba-pi" title="SPE-2702-TBA-PI" data-value="spe-2702-tba-pi">
<img class="hs-rsp-popup variation-img" src="https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/SPE-2702-TBA-PI-600x600.jpg">
<span class="middle">
<span class="variation-desc">
Dimensões: 190X190mm
Material: Alumínio Polido
Tipo: QUADRADA
Cor: Aluminio polido
</span>
<span class="variation-selected">SELECIONADO</span>
<p class="variation-select ">
<img class="var-slc-img" src="https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/wp-content/themes/sperone/img/selecionar.png">
<a class="selecionar">Selecionar</a>
<a class="selecionado">Selecionado</a>
</p>
<a href="https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/SPE-2702-TBA-PI-600x600.jpg" class="hs-rsp-popup variation-ampliar">
<img class="var-slc-img" src="https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/wp-content/themes/sperone/img/lupav.png">Ampliar
<img class="hs-rsp-popup" src="https://www.agenciagoup.com.br/projetos/sperone/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/SPE-2702-TBA-PI-600x600.jpg">
</a>
</span>
</span>
```

Comment: Não consegui perceber o problema. Vc quer que clique onde tem "✔ selecionar" para selecionar o produto?

Comment: bom dia!, isso mesmo, somente quando clicar em "SELECIONAR", não clicando em qualquer lugar do container, Att.

Comment: entendo, com o exemplo do Leite abaixo funcionou, só que agora ele não remove o selecionado ao clicar novamente.

Answer (score 2):

Pelo que percebo estás a colocar o 'onClick' no `.swatch`, que é o container da imagem e descrição da variação.

Deves mudar o teu código para adicionar o evento apenas no link **Selecionar** que é o `<a class="selecionar">Selecionar</a>`.

```
// mudar .swatch para .selecionar para o evento ser triggered no link em vez do container .swatch
$vselect.on( 'click', '.selecionar', function ( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); // para nao haver bubbling do evento para os pais
    var $el = $( this ).parents( '.swatch' ), // aqui trocava o $( this ) para que $el continue a ser o .swatch e o código abaixo continue a ser válido
```

Comment: Deu certo!, só que se eu clico novamente no "Selecionado", ele não remove o selected, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: eu tentei editar essa parte, desta forma, mas não funcionou
if ( ! $select.find( 'option[value="' + value + '"]' ).length ) {
      $vselect.siblings( '.swatch' ).removeClass( 'selected' );
      $select.val( '' ).change();
      $vselect.trigger( 'tawcvs_no_matching_variations', [$el] );
      return;
     }

Comment: O código deste bloco `if ( $el.hasClass( 'selected' ) ) {` é que controla o que fazer caso cliques numa variação que esteja ou não seleccionada. Tens de fazer ai debug e perceber se está a remover a class css correctamente e a limpar as variáveis como pretendes.

Comment: poderia me explicar melhor? não tenho muita experiência em jQuery

Answer (score 2):

Além de fazer o que propôs a resposta do @Leite, é preciso diferenciar qual link foi clicando entre `.selecionar` e `.selecionado` para alternar entre um e outro.

Para isso, acrescente no evento a classe `.selecionado`:

```
                                          ↓
$vselect.on( 'click', '.selecionar, .selecionado', function ( e ) {...
```

No `if` onde é verificado se possui a classe `.selected`, insira mais uma condição:

```
                                            ↓
if ( $el.hasClass( 'selected' ) && e.currentTarget.className == "selecionado" ) {
...
}
```

Desta forma o script saberá qual link foi clicado. Da forma anterior o script está retirando a classe `.selected` de todos os blocos, mesmo tendo adicionado antes.

Comment: Perfeito dvd, vocês são demais! muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: dvd, se puder me ajudar em mais uma função por favor, eu tentei adicionar funções paralelas para remover a classe selected depois de adicionar o produto ao carrinho, mas nada funciona, alguma maneira de contornar isso?

Comment: atualizei o código de como eu estou usando atualmente

Comment: Quais são essas funções paralelas? Não consegui visualizar no código.

Comment: eu estava tentando fazer uma "gambiarra", usando o window load pra remover a class selected, ele remove a classe, mas se eu recarrego a página ela volta, e depois some de novo, gostaria que realmente desselecionasse, também estava tentando resetar o quantity, mas não ficou bom 
 $(window).on('load', function () {
  $('.single_variation_wrap :input.qty').each(function() {
         $(this).attr('value','1');
        });
 });